# PostgreSQL isn't using indices in FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, join, postgresql-performance

I have these tables I'd like to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between. They both have an index on `(ts_minute, user_id, campaign_id, host_id)` (which matches the join condition). In the following query, if I remove `FULL OUTER` from the query, it runs 10,000 times faster because it uses the indices (confirmed using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`). Problem is, I need `FULL OUTER`.

```sql
select user_id, campaign_id, sum(i.cost), sum(b.bids_internal), sum(b.eligible_requests)
    from impr_summary_test i
    join bid_summary_test b USING (ts_minute, user_id, campaign_id, host_id)
    where ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'
    group by 1, 2 order by 1,2;
```

There are indices on just `(ts_minute)` as well. It would be nice if it could use this index. The number of rows returned in the slow case is ~330, the number of rows returned in the fast case is ~220.

Postgres 9.3.

I've tried re-writing this as two separate sub queries, each with their own (identical) `WHERE` clause, and then `JOIN`'ing those results, and that does speed it up, but the basic `INNER JOIN` case is still 5 times faster than the re-write.

How can I speed this up by getting it to use the indices?

Number of rows in bid_summary_test: 8,292,673

Number of rows in bid_summary_test that match predicate `ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'` : 28,849

Number of rows in impr_summary_test: 2,523,534

Number of rows in impr_summary_test that match predicate `ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'` : 11,081

Comment: You need to provide more information. Read the [tag info for \[postgresql-performance\]](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). For starters, your version of Postgres, cardinalities and how many rows each query returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When combining two tables with `FULL OUTER JOIN` ***all***  rows are included in the result. Typically, it doesn't make sense to use indexes for the joining columns. That's why attempts with indexes on `(ts_minute, user_id, campaign_id, host_id)` will be fruitless. It just so happens that the first column also fits the relevant predicate on `ts_minute`. See below.

The query also returns substantially **fewer rows** with an `[INNER] JOIN`, which explains *some* of the performance difference - but certainly not factor 10.000. Your updated info confirms that fewer rows are returned (220 vs. 330) but that's still not the whole story. The difference could be much bigger before aggregation.

Your predicate on `ts_minute` is the better candidate for index support. There are *two* indices that would seem applicable for the predicate `ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'` (pending information on actual data types). But the appearance is deceitful: The resulting column `ts_minute` ***after*** the `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` is a combination of the columns in both underlying tables. It's like an expression that's **not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)** and cannot use indices on `ts_minute` on the underlying tables.

You have to apply the predicate *before* the `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` to allow index support. That's what you already stumbled upon in your added test with two separate sub queries. You'll find index (only) scans or probably bitmap index scans if you inspect the `EXPLAIN` output.

Since you `GROUP BY user_id, campaign_id`, it is **irrelevant** whether you add the columns `ts_minute` and `host_id` to the join condition in this query. `ts_minute` is only necessary for the `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT user_id, campaign_id
     , i.sum_cost, b.sum_bids_internal, b.sum_eligible_requests
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, campaign_id
        , sum(cost) AS sum_cost
   FROM   impr_summary_test
   WHERE  ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) i 
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, campaign_id
        , sum(bids_internal) AS sum_bids_internal
        , sum(eligible_requests) AS sum_eligible_requests
   FROM   bid_summary_test
   WHERE  ts_minute > now() - interval '5 min'
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) b USING (user_id, campaign_id)
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Assuming that only a very small percentage of the rows in each table lie within the "last 5 minutes", an index on `ts_minute` in both tables should make this very fast.

If your write patterns and [`autovacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) allow [**index-only scans**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans), these indices would give you **best performance**:

```
CREATE INDEX ON impr_summary_test (ts_minute, user_id, campaign_id, cost);
CREATE INDEX ON bid_summary_test  (ts_minute, user_id, campaign_id, bids_internal, eligible_requests);
```

Weigh cost and benefit for highly specialized indexes.

Comment: -info moved to question-

Comment: @Eddified: Updated my answer.